# xml schema, precision of decimal value

Tags: xsd

This is my xml (not whole):

```
<xsd:complexType name="xx">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="tns:xx">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="rekVrednostDdv" nillable="true" type="decimal"/>
          <xsd:element name="xx" nillable="true" type="dateTime"/>
          <xsd:element name="xx" nillable="true" type="decimal"/>
          <xsd:element name="xx" nillable="true" type="string"/>
          <xsd:element name="xx" nillable="true" type="dateTime"/>
          <xsd:element name="xx" nillable="true" type="string"/>
          <xsd:element name="xx" nillable="true" type="decimal"/>
          <xsd:element name="xx" nillable="true" type="decimal"/>
          <xsd:element name="xx" nillable="true" type="string"/>
          <xsd:element name="xx" nillable="true" type="string"/>
          <xsd:element name="xx" nillable="true" type="decimal"/>
          <xsd:element name="xx" nillable="true" type="tns:xx"/>
          <xsd:element name="xx" nillable="true" type="dateTime"/>
          <xsd:element name="xx" nillable="true" type="string"/>
          <xsd:element name="xx" nillable="true" type="string"/>
          <xsd:element name="xx" nillable="true" type="string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

For example rekVrednostDdv must have precision 2. How can i tell this type to have precision 2.

i try like this:

```
<xsd:element name="rekVrednostDdv" nillable="true">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="decimal">
                            <xsd:precision value="6"/>
                            <xsd:scale value="2"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
```

but now i get when using http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/XML/Working_With_Simple_Types.htm

```
Invalid XML schema: 'Element <xsd:precision> is not allowed under element <xsd:restriction>.'
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Create a new simple type that restricts `xs:decimal` and use `<xs:fractionDigits/>` to define the precision. Then refer to this type in your element definition.

```
<xs:simpleType name="decimalTwoPrec">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
        <xs:fractionDigits value="2" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:element name="rekVrednostDdv" nillable="true" type="decimalTwoPrec"/>
```

For more info, see the spec http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#rf-fractionDigits

Comment: Thx for help. I add <element name="rekVrednostDdv" type="tns:decimalTwoPrec" nillable="true"/> and now i think works.